replace a number with a variable in the gfi function (PowerDynamics.jl)
I cannot replace a number with a variable in the gfi function (powerDynamics).
V_ref=0.5;
gfi = GFI(...
V_r = V_ref,
...)
Error  UndefVarError: V_ref not defined
I tried using "global V_ref", it didn't help
how replace a number with a variable in the gfi function

I solved the problem.     const V_f=0.0 ,  gfi = GFI(... V_r = V_ref, ...)
